# How to get all li element to calculate using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This list was generated using input tag  and appending the element to ul  :

```
<ul id ="add">
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>*</li>
    <li>5<li>
    <li>+<li>
    <li>3</li>
<ul>
```

This is list now I would like to iterate over it so that on the console I get **34*5+3** which can calculate using JavaScript, but how to get the value of all Li to tag together so that it is able to calculate:

The complete code is from which I would like to do the calculation :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>solve</title>
       <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
            document.querySelector('#submit').onclick =()=>{
                const li = document.createElement('li');
                li.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#number').value;
                document.querySelector('#add').append(li);
                return false;
            };
        });
       </script>

       <style>
           li{
               list-style-type: none;
               display: inline;

           }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="user-input">
            <ul id="add">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
           <form>
                <input type="text" id="number">
                <input type="submit" id="submit">
           </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Value / Text of a List item Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185963/how-to-get-value-text-of-a-list-item-javascript)

Comment: var result = '';document.querySelectorAll('#add li').forEach((ele)=> result += ele.textContent.trim());

Answer (score 4):

You can use `document.querySelector` and `textContent` to get the text which will be a string then use `eval` to calculate it.

```js
let m = [...document.querySelector("#add").children];
let val = '';
m.forEach(function(item) {
  val += item.textContent;

})

console.log(eval(val)) //34*5+3
```

```html
<ul id="add">
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>*</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>+</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over the li's using `forEach()`:

```js
var satatement = '';

document.querySelectorAll('#add li').forEach(function(item) {
  satatement += item.textContent.trim();
});

console.log(satatement, '=', eval(satatement));
```

```css
li {
   list-style-type: none;
   display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="user-input">
  <ul id="add">
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>*</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>+</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help, if the answer is what you're looking for Mark it as the **[correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** for the future readers.

Answer (score 1):

```
let text = document.querySelectorAll('#add li').reduce((text, el) => text + el.innerHTML);
```

- Use `document.querySelectorAll('#add li')` to get the list items.
- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the results to a single string by concatenating all the elements' `innerHTML` properties.

---

Of course you could also use the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of the list, which includes

> the text content of a node and its descendants

`document.querySelector('#add').textContent`, but that would include newlines between each `li`.